# Syntax Error Invalid Syntax. No idea why though

Tags: syntax, syntax-error

```
height = float(input("enter your height in m: "))
weight = float(input("enter your weight in kg: "))
bmi = weight / height ** 2
bmi2 = int(bmi)
if bmi2 < 18.5:
    print(f"Your BMI is {bmi2}, you are underweight")
    elif bmi2 > 18.5 < 25:
        print(f"Your BMI is {bmi2}, you are normal weight")
    elif bmi2 > 25 < 30:
        print(f"Your BMI is {bmi2}, you are slightly overweight")
    elif bmi2 > 30 < 35:
        print(f"Your BMI is {bmi2}, you are obese")
else:
    print(f"Your BMI is {bmi2}, you are cliniclly obese")
```

it says Syntax Error invalid syntax on "elif bmi2 > 18.5 < 25:" this part but I have no idea why

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: it's python 3.8

Comment: Then there should be a Python tag on your question. Please [edit] to add it. Also, include the **complete, exact** error message you're geetting.

Comment: Have you tried `18.5 < bmi2 < 25` instead?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is indentation. There are also a few other things that I'll explain later.

This is how your script should look in order for it to work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

height = float(input("enter your height in m: "))
weight = float(input("enter your weight in kg: "))
bmi = weight / height**2
bmi2 = int(bmi)

if bmi2 < 18.5:
    print(f"Your BMI is",bmi2," you are underweight")
elif  18.5 < bmi2 <= 24.99:
    print(f"Your BMI is",bmi2," you are normal weight")
elif 24.99 < bmi2 <= 29.99:
    print(f"Your BMI is ",bmi2," you are slightly overweight")
elif 30 <= bmi2 <= 34.99:
    print(f"Your BMI is ",bmi2," you are obese")
else:
    print(f"Your BMI is ",bmi2," you are clinically obese")
```

All of the `if` and `else` conditions should be aligned to the beginning of the line. One would only indent inside if there were a nested statement such as

```
if apple > 5;
    if orange > 3;
```

And so on and so forth. Your script doesn't have that so there doesn't need to be any indentation on the statements.

The syntax for greater than or less than should be in this format:

```
elif  value < variable < value2:
```

That sets the condition as being greater than value one but less than value two. With the way that you have it, it is, in fact, setting the condition in the first one for example, as bmi being greater than 18.5 and 18.5 being less than 25. This will cause every `bmi2` that's over 18.5 to be result in normal weight because no matter what `bmi2` is in that case, the second condition of 18.5 being less than 25 will always be true no matter what one enters.

For accuracy, I also changed `less than 25` in the second statement to  `less than or equal to 24.99`, `greater than 25` to `greater than 24.99` and `less than 30` to `less than or equal to 29.99` in the third statement, and finally, `greater than 30` to `greater than or equal to 30` and `less than 35` to `less than or equal to 34.99` in the third statement as that lines up with the ranges from the actual BMI calculator and prvents other wonkiness from overlapping values.

Now that the important things have been covered, I also made some cosmetic changes including adding a blank line between the variable declarations and using commas and quotes to separate the variable `bmi2` from the text. This makes it a bit easier to tell which one is who and what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

```
height = float(input("enter your height in m: "))
weight = float(input("enter your weight in kg: "))

height_2 = height*height
BMI = weight/height_2
BMI2=round(BMI)
if BMI2 <=18.5:
    print(f"Your BMI is {BMI2}, you are underweight.")
elif 18.6< BMI2 <= 24.99:
    print(f"Your BMI is {BMI2}, you have a normal weight.")
elif 25< BMI2 <=29.99:
    print(f"Your BMI is {BMI2}, you are slightly overweight.")
elif 30 < BMI2 <= 34.99:
    print(f"Your BMI is {BMI2}, you are obese.")
elif BMI2 > 35:
    print(f"Your BMI is {BMI2}, you are clinically obese.")
else:
    print(f"Your BMI is {BMI2}, you are clinically obese.")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).